# MySql Query Sent by Email

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a simple query that select some fields from a few different tables and I need it to run once a month. I know i can schedule a monthly "job" with the CREATE EVENT, however, is it possible to have that information emailed to some addresses after the query runs? That way i don't need to log into the server and look at the new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Mysql doesn't support Email sending.

In this case, you can develop an auxiliary program that sends the file created, and execute it with - scheduled task, Cron ...(It depends on the Operating System of the server you're using).

The auxiliary program can be like [this code](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/send-e-mail-with-attachment-in-java) adding the file/s you want to attach (attachFiles variable).

```
public class EmailAttachmentSender {

public static void sendEmailWithAttachments(String host, String port,
        final String userName, final String password, String toAddress,
        String subject, String message, String[] attachFiles)
        throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    // sets SMTP server properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.user", userName);
    properties.put("mail.password", password);

    // creates a new session with an authenticator
    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
        }
    };
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

    // creates a new e-mail message
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
    InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());

    // creates message part
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html");

    // creates multi-part
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // adds attachments
    if (attachFiles != null && attachFiles.length > 0) {
        for (String filePath : attachFiles) {
            MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            try {
                attachPart.attachFile(filePath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
        }
    }

    // sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
    msg.setContent(multipart);

    // sends the e-mail
    Transport.send(msg);

}

/**
 * Test sending e-mail with attachments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // SMTP info
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    String port = "587";
    String mailFrom = "your-email-address";
    String password = "your-email-password";

    // message info
    String mailTo = "your-friend-email";
    String subject = "New email with attachments";
    String message = "I have some attachments for you.";

    // attachments
    String[] attachFiles = new String[3];
    attachFiles[0] = "e:/Test/Picture.png";
    attachFiles[1] = "e:/Test/Music.mp3";
    attachFiles[2] = "e:/Test/Video.mp4";

    try {
        sendEmailWithAttachments(host, port, mailFrom, password, mailTo,
            subject, message, attachFiles);
        System.out.println("Email sent.");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not send email.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort to help, but could you reword your question to be a bit clearer, explain what "SO" stands for and correct the spelling of "Crond" to "Cron"? Also, can you post the relevant code from the external link into your answer instead in case the page at the link disappears in the future? You might want to read up on how to write better andsers on Stack Overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to have that information emailed to some addresses
>   after the query runs?

If you are looking for a `MySQL` built in solution then probably **NO**. This particular should be handled in application end.

So, if you are scheduling the query as `cron job` in linux (OR) `batch job` in windows then you can configure `cron` (or) `batch` to send an email to list of recipients once the query finishes.

How to configure `cron` to send mail can be checked [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332481/setup-cron-job-to-send-email-to-a-bunch-of-people-on-a-regular-basis)

Comment: i was thinking something related to a stored procedure like you can do in microsoft sql server. but based on your response, i guess i would need to output the query into excel and then have a cron job pick the file and email the user, right?

Comment: Yes that can be done as well. See here http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/sending-email-alerts-through-cron/

Answer (score 1):

Mysql does not support that functionality.

You can use a cron job (Quartz) to schedule a job every month,

where you can fetch the data and shoot an email containing your data.

Refer the below link for quartz job :

http://www.mkyong.com/java/example-to-run-multiple-jobs-in-quartz/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself but I see no reason why it shouldn't work: create a UDF (user defined function) that takes the e-mail parameters and sends out the e-mail. You can write UDFs e.g. in C++ and have so all necesssary libraries at hand.